# Pass an array to view by generate method using codeigniter calendar class

Tags: php, codeigniter, calendar

Recently, I am working with `Calendar` library of Codeigniter. I would like to pass the following array to `$this->calendar->generate();`

Array as follows-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [username] => Altab Hossen
            [branch_name] => Branch 1
            [working_date] => 2014-04-16
            [time_in] => 06:13:05
            [time_out] => 09:57:11
            [hours] => 3.7350
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [username] => Altab Hossen
            [branch_name] => Branch 1
            [working_date] => 2014-04-25
            [time_in] => 14:42:22
            [time_out] => 22:42:31
            [hours] => 8.0025
        )

)
```

**in Controller:**- I have tried as follows

```
$data['calview'] = $this->calendar->generate($arrayVariable);
$this->load->view('calendarview');
```

**in view:**

```
echo $calview;
```

Answer (score 0):

The calendar library [does not support passing multiple content data](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/libraries/Calendar.php#L221) to a single day.  It actually expect [a link as the content of the day](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/calendar.html).  If you were to generate a string for each day (which can include HTML), you should be fine by calling the calendar as follow:

```
$year = 2014;  // Change me
$month = 6;    // Change me
$arrayVariable = array(6 => "Altab Hossen from Branch 1 came in at 06:13:05 and left at 09:57:11 for a total of 3.37350 hours");
$data['calview'] = $this->calendar->generate($year, $month, $arrayVariable);
```

In the template of the calendar, you will also have to change:

```
{cal_cell_content}<a href="{content}">{day}</a>{/cal_cell_content}
{cal_cell_content_today}<div class="highlight"><a href="{content}">{day}</a></div>{/cal_cell_content_today}
```

to something like

```
{cal_cell_content}<h3>{day}</h3><p>{content}</p>{/cal_cell_content}
{cal_cell_content_today}<h3>{day}</h3><div class="highlight">{content}</div>{/cal_cell_content_today}
```

If you want to support  multiple content data per day, you will have to extend the calendar class and implement that yourself.  I really think the simplest solution would be to provide a string content that has HTML inside if needed.  It's not the cleanest, but it's most likely the "less effort" route.